# Edit Avatar position in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I would move the avatar to the right of the left bubble message and to the left of the right bubble message, just like the example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I Just figured out by myself. Here is the solution:

create a const to edit the **Message** style component

```
const customMessage = props => {
return(
<Message
{...props}
containerStyle={{
left: {
flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
},
right: {
flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
}
}}
/>
)
}
```

Then add props into **GiftedChat** component:

```
<GiftedChat 
renderMessage={props => customMessage(props)}
/>
```